# understanding Plugin destroy function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

hey guys i am very new to js and jquery in genenral and i was just going throught the plugin code of a gallery plugin , i can across the function called _loadevents , that had the following content , see below :

```
this.$navPrev.on('click.gallery', function (event) {


});

this.$navNext.on('click.gallery', function (event) {


});

this.$wrapper.on('webkitTransitionEnd.gallery transitionend.gallery OTransitionEnd.gallery', function (event) {


});
```

now `$navPrev` , `$navNext` , and `$wrapper` are obviously some HTML element , now my question is about another method i came across in the same plugin , look below :

```
destroy: function () {

    // console.log('inside destroy');

    this.$navPrev.off('.gallery');
    this.$navNext.off('.gallery');
    this.$wrapper.off('.gallery');

}
```

now i see that if this function is called all the event handlers will be taken off. now , can somebody tell me what is the necessacity of such a function , does it improve a plugins efficiency ? how or when does such a function get used and is it a common practice to write e destroy function for events in plugins ?

Thank you.

Alex-z .

Answer (score 1):

Destroy functions in plugins enable a developer to reset or remove a plugin from an element, restoring the element to before the plugin was initialised. This is useful if, for example, you have a gallery plugin that works and looks fantastic on desktop, but you don't want it on mobile. You can listen to `resize` event on `window` and if the window size is smaller than e.g. 710px then `destroy` the plugin. This will remove all the added events, undo any DOM manipulation, and restore the html elements back to how they were before the plugin was first initialised (turn-wise, if the window size is larger than 710px then initialise the plugin).

They are generally considered good practice.